# In App Billing default currency

Tags: android, coronasdk

I have problem setting the currency of my application on my android console the default price input for in app product is in "**¥ Yen**" then i set "**Auto-convert prices now**" for local prices. when you click purchased the product it doesn't not change the currency according to the location of the user, my question is how can i change the default currency of the product depending in their location when they purchased the product?

i'm using corona to make the in-App Purchased

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up your currency in your Android Developer Portal:

[image: Android In App Purchase]

You shouldn't need to set up the currencies to their location, Google Play already does that automatically.

Hope this helps!